# Can a child method have change handler in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, setstate

I was wondering **why the child component with the changed value is not getting rendered here**.

Isn't it a good idea to have a child handle its own changes or better to have the controller in the parent?

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      todos: todosData
    };
  }
  render() {
    const todoItems = this.state.todos.map(item => (
      <TodoItem key={item.id} item={item} />
    ));
    return <div className="todo-list">{todoItems}</div>;
  }
}
```

This is the Child TodoItem

```
class TodoItem extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isComp: {}
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }
  handleChange() {
    let tempObj = this.state.isComp;
    tempObj.completed = !this.state.isComp.completed;
    this.setState = { isComp: tempObj };
    console.log(this.state.isComp);
  }
  render() {
    this.state.isComp = this.props.item;
    console.log(this.state.isComp);
    return (
      <div className="todo-item">
        <input type="checkbox" checked={this.state.isComp.completed} />
        <p>{this.props.item.text}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

As you can see the state is changed with `handleChange()` but this does not fire the render. I am also not too sure if another object can be assigned to an object of the state (`let tempObj = thi.state.isComp`).

The functionality I am trying to achieve is check and uncheck a box and render accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is this?

```
this.setState = { isComp: tempObj };
```

I think it should be

```
this.setState({ isComp: tempObj });
```

Comment: Okay. Are we allowed to swear in Stackoverflow? Coz that was the error. Other than that, do you think this is a good idea to handle change in the child component. The other guy from https://scrimba.com/p/p7P5Hd/cgDqBHP I was following tutorial re-rendered the entire array as he passed the handleChange method from the parent class instead.

Comment: Ideally you would make ToDoItem as dummy as possible, so handle the change in the parent. Think of it this way, if you do the change in ToDoItem without the parent knowing then when you want to persist the list you cannot.